# How does surface tension decrease when the liquid is electrified?

Tags: surface-tension

What causes the surface tension to decrease when a liquid is electrified?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but "electrified" is not a precise technical term. Are you asking about a body of liquid that holds a _[static charge?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_electricity)_

Comment: It was written "when a liquid is electrified, surface tension decreases"

Comment: ??? After I read your question, I googled for "liquid" "static charge" and "surface tension," and I found a citation for an academic paper that would seem to answer the very question. Maybe you could find something similar.

Comment: Can you provide the link please?

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/pri/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevSeriesI.4.375